# vb classic coder to android how to transition?

Tags: android, vb6, android-2.2-froyo

I'm a VB/vba coder and would like to start android dev. Currently I'm learning Java from scratch and. Its quite tough. I've read about oop but never actually written any OO code. Java syntax is also quite foreign but I'm getting the hang of it. My question is, which is absolutely the best transition path for a vb old dog to writing for froyo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd focus on learning java first.  You might read through one of the books [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far) here.

To get started with Android, read through the [development docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html), and work through the basic [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html).

Once you are comfortable with those, then you can get started developing your own app!

Comment: Thanks. Just bought Head First Java. cant wait!!